# Modeling particles in electric and magnetic fields (software recommendations)

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, charge, plasma-physics, charge-carrier

Does anyone know of free software that would allow me to visually model particles moving in electric and magnetic fields, ideally, including magnetic fields extended/altered by ferromagnetic materials? I know EMWorks would probably do it but that costs....

Something akin to this: https://ophysics.com/em8.html

But with the ability to change the vector angles, add electric fields, distort magnetic fields etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As for commercial software, there is COMSOL: to check plasma module https://www.comsol.fr/products. CST for accelerators: https://www.3ds.com/. There is a particle module for CST, sorry, I do not have link for that, should be somewhere on the website. However, there is a price to pay.

There is also MEEP simulator for Python, however, I have not used it, so you could check this out:  https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. There might be a particle simulator, but I am not sure.

Might be also this one (Also, I am not sure if there is a particle simulator): https://openems.de/start/

Comment: SimIon (https://simion.com/) is another option.